# i am trying this command but keep getting the error of cat: '*.': no such or file directory found

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to scripting and i am trying to figure out what does this code do i have tried using every file extension and nothing worked keeps giving me the error of cat: '*.': no such or file directory found

```
for i in *."$1"

do
    cat $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a parameter.  The script will display contents of all
of the files in the current directory that end with the parameter. For
example:

```
$ echo a > FILE.txt
$ echo b > FILE1.txt
$ ./c.sh txt
a
b
```

You should also put `$i` in double quotes to prevent [word
splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and add [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).  The script
should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for i in *."$1"
do
   cat "$i"
done
```